# Is the complex definition of trigonometric functions really valid for all real numbers and complex numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis

For example, I was trying to understand/interpret the equation -
$\cos(x)=\frac{e^{\iota x}+e^{-\iota x}}{2}$. To do this, I started putting some concrete values of x. For example, at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$. But, when I did that, I faced the problem of fractional exponents. I saw that after plugging in, we get $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})=\frac{e^{\frac{\iota \pi}{2}}+e^{\frac{-\iota \pi}{2}}}{2}$. Now, by definition of square root ($^{\frac{1}{2}}$) gives two outputs for negative numbers. So, plugged in the value of $e^{\pm \iota\pi} = -1$ and found the following result - 
$\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}) = \frac{(-1)^\frac{1}{2}+(-1)^\frac{1}{2}}{2} = 0\space\vee\pm \iota$. So, is the unit circle definition wrong, or is there a problem in this solution?

Comment: $e^{\pi i/2}$ should not be calculated as $\sqrt{e^{\pi i}}$. Square roots are famously problematic with complex numbers (really it is the same problem as with real numbers and the $\pm$ phenomenon)

Comment: The exponential function does not have this ambiguity; where you run into trouble is with $(e^a)^b$ being the same as $e^{ab}$. But that ambiguity comes from the logarithm implied in the expression $(e^a)^b$.

Comment: Hey FShrike. Isn't 0.5 power referring to the square root. I just checked Wolfram alpha, where it says that nth roots can have n roots (sometimes soen are degenerate).Also, square root is just nth root with n=2. Also, Ian, could you explain where the laws of exponents fail so that this issue is addressed. Also, if they are true in this case, then the above statement is wrong.

Comment: There isn't a square root implied in the expression $e^{i\pi/2}$. It means "Go counterclockwise around $z=0$ from $z=1$ by $\pi/2$ radians". You do that and you end up at $i$. In general with complex numbers all you can say is that one of the values of $(e^a)^b$ is $e^{ab}$, but there are others, given by $e^{ab+2\pi i b n}$ for each integer $n$ (you have one such expression for each value of $\log(e^a)$).

Comment: That is too geometric, is there an algebraic way to define this? Like all common functions and relations are defined. Also, I am just in High School (11th grade India), so this is all new territory for me. Also, your idea clearly introduces a new variable z which is not clearly defined, so it doesn't make sense.

Comment: it is customary when dealing with expressions involving complex numbers to use $z$ as the complex variable, and $x$ and $y$ for real variables, generally with $z = x +iy$. It is such a common custom that people rarely explain it, which can make it harder for newcomers to understand what is going in.

Comment: No. I meant that I don't understand how we can go counterclockwise around a number like z (especially when z = 0). This is because, even when we plot it on an argand plane, z = 0 does not indicate any direction.

Comment: $z=0$ is the center of rotation, you go counterclockwise around that center from $z=1$. That's well-defined (once you accept your vantage point as being above the plane).

Comment: Yeah. @Ian, I understood that, but I I want to know about why the one by nth power doesn't represent the nth root.

Comment: There is no $1/2$ power actually appearing here. There is just the power of $i\pi/2$, as one number.

Comment: Yeah. Could you elaborate on why that is so? Where am I going wrong? I don't understand how the power notation isn't functioning here. Note, that I am using the laws of exponents here. This separates the $e^{i\pi}$ from the fractional power in case of the example I mentioned above. Thanks for helping.

Comment: The laws of exponents don't hold in the same way with complex numbers. One of the values of $(e^{i\pi})^{1/2}$ is $e^{i\pi/2}$ but the other is not. The reason is because general exponentiation $a^b$ for $a \neq 0$ is *defined* as $e^{b \ln(a)}$, and this expression has multiple values whenever $a$ is not a positive real number, because of the fact that $e^{2\pi i n}=1$ for any integer $n$.

Comment: Basically, general exponentiation is not the fundamental object here, the exponential function is. Unfortunately, students generally are exposed to general exponentiation before the exponential function, and so they think of general exponentiation as more fundamental, and try to think of the exponential function in terms of it. (This is a reason to introduce the exponential function the first time with the notation $\exp(x)$ and only write it as $e^x$ once the connection back to general exponentiation is seen.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exponential and trigonometric functions are first defined on real numbers, and those definitions are generally made using properties of real numbers that are not shared by complex numbers.

So how do we even define what $e^{ix}$ should be? The answer is by Taylor series. $e^x, \cos x, \sin x$ all have power series representations that can be proven for real numbers from their real number definitions:
$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac {x^n}{n!} = 1 + x + \frac 1{2!}x^2 + \frac 
1{3!}x^2 + \dots\\
\cos x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\dfrac {x^{2n}}{(2n)!} = 1 - \frac 1{2!}x^2 +\frac 1{4!}x^4+ \dots\\ 
\sin x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\dfrac {x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} = x - \frac 1{3!}x^3 +\frac 1{5!}x^5+ \dots$$

However, unlike the original definitions of these functions on real numbers, these Taylor series work just as well for complex numbers as they do for real numbers, so we **define** these functions for complex numbers by using the Taylor series with a variable over the complex numbers instead of just real numbers. (For for these three functions, the series converges to a limit for all values of the variable.)
$$e^z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac {z^n}{n!} = 1 + z + \frac 1{2!}z^2 + \frac 
1{3!}z^2 + \dots\\
\cos z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\dfrac {z^{2n}}{(2n)!} = 1 - \frac 1{2!}z^2 +\frac 1{4!}z^4+ \dots\\ 
\sin z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\dfrac {z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} = z - \frac 1{3!}z^3 +\frac 1{5!}z^5+ \dots$$

Now $i^n$ cycles repeatedly through the four values $1, i, -1, -i$. In particular, when $z = ix$, we can do this calculation
$$\begin{align}e^{ix} &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac 1{n!}i^nx^n\\
&=\left(\sum_{n \equiv 0\bmod 4} \dfrac 1{n!}x^n - \sum_{n \equiv 2\bmod 4} \dfrac 1{n!}x^n\right)+ i\left(\sum_{n \equiv 1\bmod 4} \dfrac 1{n!}x^n  - \sum_{n \equiv 3\bmod 4} \dfrac 1{n!}x^n\right)\\
&=\left(\sum_{n \equiv 0\bmod 2} (-1)^{n/2}\dfrac 1{n!}x^n\right) + i\left(\sum_{n \equiv 1\bmod 2} (-1)^{(n-1)/2}\dfrac 1{n!}x^n\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\dfrac 1{(2k)!}x^{2k} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\dfrac 1{(2k+1)!}x^{2k+1}\\
&=\cos x + i\sin x\end{align}$$

Cosine is an even function, $\cos(-x) = \cos x$, while sine is an odd function, $\sin(-x) = -\sin(x)$. Thus we also have
$$e^{-ix} = \cos(-x) + i\sin(-x) = \cos x - i\sin x$$
If you add the expressions for $e^{ix}$ and $e^{-ix}$ together, or take their difference, you get

$$e^{ix} + e^{-ix}= 2\cos x\\
e^{ix} - e^{-ix}= 2\sin x$$
Dividing by $2$ gives your identities.

Comment: Yeah. I do understand the derivation. I also understand the fact that it should be applicable for real and other complex numbers. The part that I don't understand is the application part. I intend to put concrete values and check. If you would try putting the following values $x=\pi/2$, $x=\pi/3$, $x=\pi/4$, etc. This is to really check if the complex definition works. When, I put the values I encountered nth roots (with n = 2, 3, 4 in the above examples), whose definition you can find here-[link](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/nthRoot.html). By definition, nth roots can have multiple solutions

Comment: You claim to understand the derivation, but then follow that claim with remarks that clearly contradict it. $e^{ix}$ is defined by the Taylor series. There are *no* roots being taken in that Taylor series. That Taylor series *is the definition* of $e^{i\pi/2}, e^{i\pi/3}$, etc., and it gives only one value for them. Yes, there are other roots of $e^{i\pi} = -1$. But those other roots are **not** the value of these powers of $e$.

Comment: Yeah. The purpose of this question is to remove that contradiction. I would really appreciate if you could elaborate on why $e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}$ does not have a square root. Because the power notation is represented like that. Also, I have tried to use the laws of exponents to remove that square root from $e^{i\pi}$ to form $(e^{i\pi})^{\frac{1}{2}}$. If I am wrong, I apologize.

Comment: There is no contradiction, just you refusing to let go of a bad idea and actually pay attention to what I've been telling you. Just where in $$e^{i\pi/2} = 1 + i\frac\pi 2 + \frac 1{2!}\left(i\frac\pi2\right)^2 + \frac 1{3!}\left(i\frac\pi2\right)^3 + \frac1{4!}\left(i\frac\pi2\right)^4 +\dots$$ do you see fractional powers? That is the definition of $e^{i\pi/2}$. There is no other definition. Before you can use $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$, you have to prove that it holds for complex numbers. Instead what you have is a counter-example showing that it does *not* hold in general for complex numbers.

Comment: More generally $z^w$ where $z, w$ can be complex numbers is only well-defined when (1) $z > 0$ is real, (2) $w$ is an integer, (3) $z = 0, w \ne 0$. You can make a definition for it in other cases, but that definition is only going to be applicable to a limited number of calculations, and someone else may need to make their own definition for different calculations. This is the reason we don't have a common definition for it that everyone uses. It is more helpful to leave it undefined in general, and let people make the definition (called a branch-cut) they need when they need it.

Comment: Ok. So, if I plugin the values, I would get a decent approximation of this value, not the actual value itself. So, is there any way to get the actual value from the above definition. How do you evaluate this infinite series?

Comment: There is no such thing as "getting the actual value" for any number that is not rational. All you can do is find ways to calculate the value to any desired-but-non-zero level of error, though for small error limits, it becomes impractical to actually carry out that calculation. We do not know the exact values of $e$ or $\pi$. We don't even know the exact value of $\sqrt 2$. We know that each of these numbers exist, because we set up the rules so that they would. But the "exact value" is impossible to know. But we know all of them well-enough for any practical calculation that uses them.

Comment: No. I meant that can you prove that of $e^{\frac{\iota\pi}{2}} = \iota$ using the above definition.

Comment: Yes. These Taylor series did not just come out of nowhere. You can prove that they each converge over real numbers to their respective functions. For non-real numbers, this isn't even a proof, its a definition. Thus every exact value of these functions that you know, and every property that is provable about them by other means, are all proved automatically to hold for the Taylor series.

Comment: Oh. So, how to prove $e^{\frac{\iota\pi}{2}} = \iota$ using Taylor series?

Comment: As I described in the previous comment, you prove that $e^x, \cos x, \sin x$ are each equal to their Taylor series. Expand by definition to $e^z$ where $z = x + iy$. Apply some algebra and theorem $\lim (u + v) = \lim u + \lim v$ to the Taylor series to show that $e^{iy} = \cos y +i\sin y$. Then set $y = \frac \pi 2$.

Comment: Then, how do you prove that $\cos(\pi/2) = 0$ and $\sin(\pi/2) = 1$ using Taylor series (as that is a valid definition of $\cos$ and $\sin$ as far as I know). When you plug in the values, you get terms of $\pi^n$ which are very problematic.

Comment: $\cos \frac \pi 2$ and $\sin \frac \pi 2$ are NOT defined by the Taylor series. (Note that they are real values, and for real values, the functions are defined first, and then the Taylor series, it is only for non-real values that this is flipped.) They are defined geometrically on the unit circle. There it is quite obvious that they are $0$ and $1$ respectively. The proof that the Taylor series converges to the respective functions is then sufficient to prove that the sums for each also converge to $0$ and $1$. Proofs of convergence of the Taylor series to these functions are easy to find.